# How to catch the TouchEvent in Activity and don't let it pass to child view?

Tags: android

I want to catch the TouchEvent in Activity when Spinner is focused, I don't want the TouchEvent/ClickEvent can pass to Spinner if Spinner is focused, but it seems that Activity must pass the MotionEvent to it's child view, I was confused about it.Can someone give me an available advice? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Any code? Not sure exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I don't know for sure what you want, but add `android:clickable="false"` to spinner tag in your xml file